# How to emit Qtsignal from one class which results to emit Qtsignal from its parent class in pyqt

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

i have a requirement where my execution will happen in threads and i want to emit signal from that thread to main class. below is my example code snippet, where i created the an instance of `MainClass` and assigned it to `temp`. where `MainClass` internally is connected to a thread `Thread1` where the actual work will happen. when the signal is emitted from `Thread1` i want the `signalcalled` definition to be executed which is connected from `temp`

**Code snippet**

```
class Thread1(QtCore.QThread):

    ThreadSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    While True:

        #some statments
        if Condition:
            ThreadSignal.emit('Yes')
        else:
            ThreadSignal.emit('No')

class MainClass(QtCore.QObject):

    MainSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    Testinstance = Thread1()

def signalcalled(s):

    print s

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = AtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    temp = MainClass()
    temp.MainSignal.connect(signalcalled)
    sys.exit(app.exec()_)
```

Comment: Have you tried `thread1.ThreadSignal.connect(self.MainSignal.emit)`?

Comment: @Blender if i use `thread1.ThreadSignal.connect(self.MainSignal.emit)` then in a situation when i have 2 instances of `MainClass` and each have to run different def on emit of signal from `Thread1` will be an issue

Comment: Is `Testinstance` a class variable or an instance variable?

Comment: @Blender `Testinstance` is an instance of `Thread1` class in `MainClass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class myThread(QtCore.QThread):
    threadSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myThread, self).__init__(parent)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if True:
                self.threadSignal.emit('Yes')

            else:
                self.threadSignal.emit('No')

            break

class myMainClass(QtCore.QObject):
    mainSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myMainClass, self).__init__(parent)

        testInstance = myThread(self)
        testInstance.threadSignal.connect(self.mainSignal.emit)
        testInstance.start()

def signalcalled(s):
    print s

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import  sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = myMainClass()
    main.mainSignal.connect(signalcalled)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Got the solution, Your is working. and the other workaround is just connect the thread signal to main signal. Instead of this `testInstance.threadSignal.connect(self.mainSignal.emit)` we can use 'testInstance.threadSignal.connect(self.mainSignal)' without emit also it is working. thx for the help +1

Answer (score 0):

```
class Thread1(QtCore.QThread):

    ThreadSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super(myThread, self).__init__()

    def run(self):

        While True:

            #some statments
            if Condition:
                ThreadSignal.emit('Yes')
            else:
                ThreadSignal.emit('No')

class MainClass(QtCore.QObject):

    MainSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):

        super(myThread, self).__init__()

        Testinstance = Thread1()
        Testinstance.ThreadSignal.connect(MainSignal)
        Testinstance.start()

def signalcalled(s):

    print s

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = AtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    temp = MainClass()
    temp.MainSignal.connect(signalcalled)
    sys.exit(app.exec()_)
```